# How to select data from left join table?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have tow entities: Users and Settings tables.

```
@Entity()
export class Users {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;
    
    @Column()
    settingID: number;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Settings {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;
}
```

How to select data from Settings table ?

```
        return this.usersRepository
            .createQueryBuilder("users")
            .select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'settings.name'])
            .leftJoinAndSelect(Settings, 'settings', 'users.settingID = settings.id')
            .getMany();
```

Now I don't get data from Settings table, only users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return this.usersRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("users")
    .select(['users.id', 'users.name'])
    .leftJoinAndSelect('users.settings', 'settings', 'users.settingID = settings.id')
    .addSelect(['settings.name', 'settings.prop1', 'settings.prop2'])
    .getMany();
```

or

```
return this.usersRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("users")
    .leftJoinAndSelect('users.settings', 'settings', 'users.settingID = settings.id')
    .select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'settings.name', 'settings.prop1', 'settings.prop2'])
    .getMany();
```

Comment: how to do it without linking tables?

Comment: Could you specify which result do you expect?

Comment: I have two unrelated tables. Without users.settings relation.

Comment: Not sure about it for now. If I remember or found smth helpful I'll update the answer and ping you

Comment: ``` .getRawMany ```